# Check if jQuery method exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible? No matter how, in Javascript or jQuery.

For example: `$.isFunction($.isFunction());`

Upd: But how to check method of a jQuery plugin? Sometimes it not ready at the moment of it call and generates error. Example: `$.isFunction($().jqGrid.format)`

Answer (score 8):

To pass a function to another function, leave the `()` off:

```
$.isFunction($.isFunction);   // true!
```

When you write `()` you are *calling* the function, and using the result it returns. `$.isFunction()` with no argument returns `false` (because `undefined` isn't a function), so you are saying `$.isFunction(false)`, which is, naturally, also `false`.

I wouldn't bother using `isFunction` merely to check for the existence of something, unless you suspect that someone might have assigned a non-function value to it for some reason. For pure existence-checking, use the `in` operator:

```
if ('isFunction' in $) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return jQuery(this).length>0;}

if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // code........
}
```